# When using a "shareReplay" pipe used width an HttpClient.get be ha hot or cold Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

When using a shareReplay pipe in a HttpClient.get Observable be hot or cold? Do i need to unsubscribe the subscriptions using it?

I just need to call it ones in an other service and set a variable in an init method. Just wonder if I need to run an unsubscribe or if it is completed. Then i do not need to add the cleanup function.

```
 // RolesService
constructor(private http: HttpClient)
...
// will this return a cold or hot observable
getRoles():Observable<Role[]> {
  return http.get<Role[]>("roles url", {}).pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
// A caller an other service
checkRole() {
  this.roleSubscribe = this.roleService.getRoles().subscribe(r => 
       this.handleRoles(r));
}

cleanUp() {
  // is this already done or complete so i don't need to do this?
  this.roleSubscribe.unSubscribe();
}
```

Comment: There are not enough details to understand your question and give a competent answer. Try improving it by adding code examples and clarifying the exact problem you are trying to solve (or just worrying about)

Comment: Was a little quick there, but added some code and little more context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Angular`'s `http` returns Cold Observables. Any new subscriptions will trigger the execution once again (meaning the request will be send as many times as there are subscriptions).

To avoid this use `share`,`shareReplay`, `publish`, `publishLast` or `publishReplay`

Comment: Yes that is what I using it for, so only have one call to the server. But are a little unsure if the shareReplay turns it to a hot. I don't think so, but are noe 100% sure.

Comment: The `shareReplay` uses `ReplaySubject` to emit last _n_ values. `ReplaySubject` is a `hot` Observable itself, so the outer observable also becomes hot

Comment: This example contradicts the hot observable theory, as the HTTP request doesn't happen despite using shareReplay.  A subscription seems to be required: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-32ic8a?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter

Comment: @alcfeoh, you need at least 1 subscription in order for the Observable to execute, this is the basis. What's happening next distinguishes cold and hot observables - hot will not be re-executed, cold will.

Answer (score 1):

Is the call to getRoles completed allthough you've added a shareReplay?

The answer is yes and you can verify it by adding a complete function to the observer object when you subscribe

```
this.rolesService.getRoles().subscribe({
  next: x => console.log(x),
  error: err => console.log(err),
  complete: () => console.log('completed')
});
```

BUT it is not enough to call shareReplay to cache values. In your example you are creating a new observable every time you call getRoles and the result will not be cached. If you inspect the network tab in devTools you will see that new http requests will be made every time you call the function.

Instead your service could have a public observable like this

```
// RolesService
roles$ = this.getRoles.pipe(shareReplay(1))

getRoles():Observable<Role[]> {
  return http.get<Role[]>("roles url", {});
}
```

And in your component

```
checkRole() {
  this.roleSubscribe = this.rolesService.roles$.subscribe(r => 
    this.handleRoles(r));
}
```

Comment: You are so right this is what we ended up doing, using the public observable. And we never get more than one call to the server per user ,a lot of our services and components are using it.